# tkinter "Class" has no attribute "button" even though is set in an instance

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying run example from this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/articles/tkinterlongruntask/) and getting an error:

```
self.startBtn.config(state=tk.DISABLED) AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'startBtn'
```

I rewrite my code for simplicity (and get still the error):

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import tkinter as tk


    class Example(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.grid()

            startBtn = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.disableButton)
            startBtn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=tk.E)

        def disableButton(self):
            self.startBtn.config(state=tk.DISABLED)


    def main():

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("400x300")
        app = Example(root)
        app.mainloop()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

What I missed?

---

Actualization
I forgot mention that program is able to compile and error occurs when button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *function*, you use:

```
def disableButton(self):
    self.startBtn.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

but the *button is created* without `self`:

```
startBtn = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.disableButton)
startBtn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=tk.E)
```

Simply make it:

```
    self.startBtn = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.disableButton)
    self.startBtn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=tk.E)

def disableButton(self):
    self.startBtn.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

...to be able to configure the button's state in the function.

Comment: thanks! I though that self.sth(...) is only a syntastic sugar for sth(self, ...)